# Mocking a field initialized in a @Tested class using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit

I have a class like this

```
class ClassA {
  @Injected
  Dao daos;

  private String str = ClassB.getString();

  public void myMethod(){
   useMyString(str);
  }
}
```

In the above code I have a class ClassA that uses several Injectables injected in by a dependency injection framework. It has a variable str which it obtains from a static method in ClassB and is used later in myMethod() method. I want to test myMethod() method but I was to mock the variable str. I am using a TestNG test as shown below:

```
class ClassATest{
  @Injectable
  Dao dao;

  @Tested
  ClassA classA;

  @Mocked 
  ClassB classB;

  @Test
  public void myTest(){
    new NonStrictExpectations(){
      {
         ClassB.getString(anyString);
         result = "mocked"
      }
    }
    classA.myMethod();
  }
}
```

In the above test since the classA has already been initialized by JMockit since it is annotated as @Tested the NonStrictExpectations block doesn't have any effect. I was wondering how can I have the mock definition take effect when the @Tested class is being initialized?

Comment: Initially, I thought you wanted to mock ClassB.getString() rather than ClassB.findString(anyString)...but then I saw it wasn't as simple as that.

Comment: A hint: notice that `@Tested` has attributes... and API documentation.